# Mongo fetch request is too long for the last iteration with indexes

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I try to fetch some data from large mongoDB collection. I am using mongoose with mongo-cursor-pagination plugin. The data I want to fetch could be also massive, so I fetch data by chunks.

```
const getTotalCountFn = async () => await this.countDocuments(filters);

const processChunkFn = async (index) => {
  // query is {accountId: {$eq: '...'}, statuses.0.date: {$gt: ...}}
  const response = await this.model.paginate({query, next, limit: LIMIT}); 
  await processFn(response.results); // save to some variable
  return {
    next: response.next,
    hasNext: response.hasNext,
    data: response.results,
    count: response.results.length
  };
};

return await this.runTask({
  startIndex: null,
  getTotalCountFn,
  processChunkFn,
  onSuccess,
  onFailed
}));

///

private async runTask({processChunkFn, getTotalCountFn, startIndex, onSuccess, onFailed}) {
  try {
    const total = await getTotalCountFn();
    let count = 0;
    let hasNext = total > 0;
    let index = startIndex;
    while (hasNext) {
        console.time('db request');
        const chunkResult = await processChunkFn(index);
        console.timeEnd('db request');
        count += chunkResult.count;
        hasNext = chunkResult.hasNext;
        index = chunkResult.next;

        const progress = total > 0 ? Math.round(count / total * 100) : 100;
        void this.setProgress(task, progress);
    }
    const data = await onSuccess();
    await this.complete(task, data);
  } catch (error) {
    ...
  }
}
```

In my schema I init plugin and add indexes to improve performance

```
Schema.plugin(MongoPaging.mongoosePlugin);
Schema.index({'statuses.0.date': 1});
Schema.index({'accountId': 1});
Schema.index({'accountId': 1, 'statuses.0.date': 1});
```

I fetch 300k rows with such a request and I have 1000 rows per chunk. In console I have something like this:

```
db request: 49.033ms
db request: 68.441ms
db request: 52.12ms
db request: 49.778ms
db request: 44.02ms
db request: 36.716ms
db request: 34.983ms
db request: 18.170s
```

Please note the last request takes too much time (18s) compare to others (~50ms). And I have no idea why does this happen.

Why it takes too much time?

Maybe mongo-cursor-pagination plugin is not best for my operation?

1. I checked event loop delay with blocked-at npm library. It looks ok. It is not overloaded
2. I changed chunk size: 500, 4000. It does not really affects execution time
3. I tried work without the plugin and fetch data without using indexes with `find().limit().offset().lean()` it takes even more time
4. I tried to set `limit` for the last iteration with `total - count - 1` and it helps. I don't really like such an approach because I lose some data

Comment: I also tried mongoose-paginate-v2 plugin but it works 10 times slower for every iteration